# How to pass an operator as default functor argument?

Tags: c++, templates, operators, default, functor

For simplicity, let's say I want to do implement a function which takes two parameters and predicate which test for equality,

```
template<typename T, typename TCompare>
bool Eq(const T& a, const T& b, const TCompare& cmp) {
  return cmp(a, b);
}
```

but I also want that `operator==` is assumed if predicate is not passed.

I tried several different approaches, but all resulted in either syntax error or "operator==" not defined. I even tried replacing the `Eq` function with a

Nevertheless, I suppose what I want is possible since the big part of STL supports not passing the optional TCompare parameter (std::sort, std::set ...).

**UPDATE**:
Thanks to levis501 suggestion, this is the best way I have found so far:

```
template<typename T, typename TCompare>
bool Eq(const T& a, const T& b, const TCompare& cmp) {
  return cmp(a, b); // or some lengthy code
}

template<typename T>
bool Eq(const T& a, const T& b) {
  static std::equal_to<T> EqCmp;
  return Eq(a, b, EqCmp);
}
```

So, you basically need to create a wrapper which passes std::equal_to, or any other operator-equivalent functor. For some reason, having it as a default argument does not compile when you invoke the function without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about std::equal_to ?  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/equal_to/

Comment: That's what I am looking for. But I am still a bit disappointed because I cannot just set is as a default argument. But I managed to find the solution, so I'll update the original post.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I wonder if you could use std::equal_to as a default parameter for cmp.  Did you try this?

Comment: http://ideone.com/RdrsT This doesn't work because the type of the functor apparently can't be deduced from the default argument. - It would work if you tell the type (http://ideone.com/clone/tcGUA) but then the default does very little.

Comment: http://ideone.com/clone/CJP5a -- Instead of using stl functors equal_to<T>, less<T>, etc., how about function pointers of your own design?

Answer (score 1):

You can overload functions, no?

```
// Use the user-supplied TCompare.
template<typename T, typename TCompare> 
bool Eq(const T& a, const T& b, TCompare cmp) { 
  return cmp(a, b); 
} 

// Use op== for equality otherwise.
template<typename T> 
bool Eq(const T& a, const T& b) { 
  return a == b; 
}
```

If the code calls `Eq()` with three arguments, the compiler will resolve the call to the first overload. If the code calls `Eq()` with only two arguments, then the compiler will have to resolve to the second overload.

Comment: Ok, this is acceptable for simple cases like this. But suppose the function is 1000 liner. Then, this approach requires copying and pasting body function and replacing operator== with cmp, right?

Comment: @leden: Then you need to break up your function into smaller functions. 1000 lines is way too much for a single function. Factor out common code into their own functions, then have `Eq()` call them as necessary.

Comment: I know. That's not the point. I am trying to say that if you do it like this, and call another function which calls another function etc. You will have to create 2 versions of each of these functions which are called, which means a lot of code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

I don't suppose something like the following would work for you:

```
#include <functional>

template<typename T, typename TCompare = std::equal_to<T>>
class Math {
public:
    static bool Eq(const T& a, const T& b) {
        TCompare cmp;

        return cmp(a, b);
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    Math<int>::Eq(1,1);

    return 0;
}
```

Default template parameters are only allowed on class templates (or at least that's what MSVC 10 says)